# PHP not recognizing array keys that are set using file headers

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

I am trying up a script that consumes a tab separated file and makes each row into an array to be submitted into a DB.

The first row in the file are headers, my goal is to use the headers as the array keys for the data to be submitted to the DB.

My problem is that even though the headers are successfully being set as the keys, the keys are not recognized for some reason and I am getting "undefined index" notices in my log when I call specific values like $data['Company'].

When I do a print_r it looks like this:

```
Array (
    [Company] => Parking
    [Department] => 2290333
    [First Name] => JOE
    [Last Name] => SMITH
    [Hint] => LAST NAME
    [Hint answer] => SMITH
    [Add-Delete] => Add )
```

Here is what my function looks like so far:

```
public function updatePeople($file) {
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $inactives = array(); //an array to contain the jde numbers of locations not in the .csv
        $i = 0;

        if ($file['file']['size'] > 0) {

            $type = $file['file']['type'];
            if($type == 'text/plain') {

                $tmp_name = $file['file']['tmp_name'];
                $handle = fopen($tmp_name,"r");

                while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,"\t")) {

                    if($i != 0) {  //skip headers
                        $data = array_combine($keys,$data);

                        print '<p>' . $data['Company'] . '</p>';  //results in undefined index notice
                        print '<pre>'; print_r($data); print '</pre>'; //prints the key/vals just fine

                    }
                    else {  //convert first line to array keys
                        $keys = $data;
                        $keys = array_map('trim', $keys);
                        $keys[0] = substr($keys[0], 2); //trim off artifact that appears at beginning of first header

                    }

                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
```

I know I can do this other ways, like forgoing with the headers and calling the array values by the default numerical keys, but that wouldn't lead to as dynamic handling.

Comment: Double check your code and the CSV file for typos.

Comment: I'm assuming the `$keys[0] = substr($keys[0], 2);` is there to remove a unicode BOM?

Comment: Yes.  However, all keys return the same "undefined index" notice.